# c# concatenation troubles (new to c#)

Tags: c#, .net, string-concatenation

Alright so I'm trying to concatenate two strings from a text file together and store them into an array. The problem is is that it seems that when the strings are being concatenated it places the second string to the beginning of the first.

Code:

```
//grabs the lines from the text file
private static string[] ReadFile()
    {
        string line = "";

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Links.txt"))
            {
                line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            // Breaks the lines into categories
            string[] categories = BreakContentIntoCategories(line);
            return categories;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static string[] BreakContentIntoCategories(string lines)
    {
        string[] categories = new string[3];
        int place = 0;

        string[] line = lines.Split('\n');
        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            if (line[i][0] == '#')
            {
                string[] category = new string[2];
                category[0] = line[i].Substring(1);
                category[1] = line[i + 1];
                Console.WriteLine(category[0]);
                Console.WriteLine(category[1]);
                // Problem lies here
                Console.WriteLine(category[0] + category[1]);
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
                categories[place] = string.Join("",category);
                place++;
            }
        }

        return categories;
    }
```

So when I do the

```
Console.WriteLine(category[0] + category[1]);
```

It returns

```
BOTW urlThe Worst
```

When it should return

```
Best Of The WorstBOTW url
```

Text File:

```
#Plinkett
plinkett url

#Half In The Bag
HITB url

#Best Of The Worst
BOTW url
```

Any help is appreciated and anymore info needed just tell me and I will add it to the post.

This has been solved thanks to an anonymouse user, Jakob Olsen, and Francesca Aldrovandi thank you all!

**Solution**: I had completely forgot that when you read a file there will be characters such as \r and \n added at the end and I wasn't removing them when reading the lines. So I'm currently using Francesca Aldrovandi's advice and using the replace method to easily remove them.

Thank you all for your advice on my problem!

Comment: What do the two console writes above that line do? do they print out the correct items?

Comment: Did you debug your code and looks what are `category[0]` and `category[1]` values?

Comment: Btw, you could use `File.ReadAllLines` instead of your `StreamReader.ReadToEnd` + `lines.Split('\n')` approach.

Comment: @SonerGönül: he posted `Console.WriteLine(category[0]);
                Console.WriteLine(category[1]);`

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Thats the text file, not the output

Comment: @Sayse:i'm afraid that you've lost me there. He's outputting both strings right before he concatenates them and outputs the result(_"Problem lies here"_). If the output was `Best Of The Worst` + `BOTW url` but the next concatenation output was `BOTW urlThe Worst` i understand OP's confusion.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - It seems like the problem isn't with the concatenation but the fact that the two values don't hold what the OP is expecting. (Looks to me like it should have a `#` as `category[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are splitting on "\n", but the newlines 'character' is in fact "\r\n". This means that most of your lines will end with "\r" which means that your Console.WriteLine doesn't work.... You are not printing the actual contents of the variables.

I have modified the code a bit, so it should do what you expect.

```
private static string[] BreakContentIntoCategories(string lines)
    {
        string[] categories = new string[3];
        int place = 0;

        lines = lines.Replace("\r\n", "\n");

        string[] line = lines.Split('\n');
        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            if (line[i].StartsWith("#"))
            {
                string[] category = new string[2];
                category[0] = line[i].Substring(1);
                category[1] = line[i + 1];
                Console.WriteLine(category[0]);
                Console.WriteLine(category[1]);
                // Problem lies here
                Console.WriteLine(category[0] + category[1]);
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
                categories[place] = string.Join("", category);
                place++;
            }
        }

        return categories;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from how you read your text file.
StreamReader.ReadToEnd method here will add \n, \r characters in your string. 
Let focus here on the \r character which is carriage return. 
When you will concatenate your differents strings which contain that character, you will lose a part of the first string and the second string will be printed  first.
Try to delete the \r character from the strings

Comment: That is exactly what the problem was! I completely forgot about the fact that the end of a line will add those characters. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the "\r" char from the end of the line.

```
category[0] = line[i].Substring(1).Replace("\r", "");
category[1] = line[i + 1].Replace("\r", "");
```